# grails 2.3.1 issue with maxSize of 25000 with mysql

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I get a strange behaviour applying constrainst to a string text into my Domain class :

```
class MyClass {
    String field

    static constraints = {
    field nullable: true, maxSize: 25000
    }
}
```

When applying a maxSize of 25000 to my field, I get the following error from console :

```
Column length too big for column 'promo_text' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
```

Changing the maxSize solve my problem, but why does GORM did not automatically convert it ?

Where can I report this ?

Snite

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set max size then you can use `type: "text"`, like

```
class MyClass {
  String field

  static constraints = {
    field nullable: true
  }

  static mapping = {
    field type: "text"
  }
}
```